# How do I issue a modifying query to remove a set of entities by their IDs with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to remove a very large number of records from my database. Each record has a cascade of Foreign Key such that, when deleting a record at a time via JPA, each removal requires around 5s.

So I decided to write a JPQL query like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, Long> {
    @Query("delete from MyTable where id in :ids")
    void deleteAllIds(@Param("ids") Long[] ids);
}
```

When I run this, or equivalently, `void deleteAllIds(@Param("ids") Set<Long> ids);`, I get the following:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [delete from com.lh.clte.domain.content.business.Hotel where id in (:ids_0_, :ids_1_, :ids_2_, :ids_3_, ... for the entire array size)]
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:293)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.deleteAllId(Unknown Source)
```

How can I get to my goal?

Comment: You cannot call delete query directly. You have to get a List of parent objects back, iterate through them, call session.delete(list.item.1). Then outside for loop, flush the session.

Comment: I am going for something like this: Set<MyTable> objectsToDelete = myTableRepository.findByIdIn(idSet);
  myTableRepository.delete(objectsToDelete);

Comment: I just posted an answer for you. Check it.

Comment: @WeareBorg - That's blatantly incorrect. You can of course issue a delete directly.

Comment: @Oliver's answer below is correct.  You are simply missing `@Modifying` on your `delete` method.  Add that and you are all set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To execute a modifying query you need to annotate the method with `@Modifying` as described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries).

Note, that issuing a delete query will not cause any lifecycle callbacks of the affected entities to be called as the statement is executed against the database directly. To get the callbacks called issue a `findAll(…)` given the list of identifiers ad pipe the results into `deleteAll(…)`.

If you don't manage transactions in any of the above layers, make sure you also use `@Transactional` so that the query execution is running in a transaction as required by JPA.

Comment: Can you give some code on how the user asking the question can achieve that... I am also interested to know.

Comment: The answer describes exactly what's needed to do: add an annotation to the method. The linked section of the reference has an example.

Comment: Plus, the `delete` method must be annotated with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Thank you Oliver, that totally fixes my performance issues: 70k entities deleted in a few seconds, taking with them around 500k linked entities.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write a separate service or class that you can write some raw sql in. JPA does allow you to write native sql, but if you're going to go that far with it you should just write some raw sql and handle it yourself, making sure that you delete the record and any associated records in other tables that the FK applies to.

Comment: Thanks, but the structure is too complex to manually handle FK. So, this is not a solution for me.

Comment: Thanks it is really helpful and cleaner approach.